# Simple Factorial Challenge

Tags: code-golf, math, number, arithmetic, number-theory

In light of today's date...

A factorial of a number n, is the product of all the numbers from 1 to n inclusive.

### The Challenge

Given an integer n where 0 <= n <= 420, find the sum of the digits of n!. It's that simple :P

*Notes: I feel like this challenge isn't too simple, as some languages have a very hard time storing numbers that are fairly large. Also, coding a BigInteger datatype is fairly straightforward, but hard to golf.*

---

### Examples

> Input: 100. Output: 648.
>
> Input: 200. Output: 1404.
>
> Input: 420. Output: 3672.

---

### Scoring

- The input and output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

EDIT: Ok, I guess it's actually easy...take a look at the Jelly answer below. Anyways, I guess we all know which one's going to be accepted. But, I'd still like to see some interesting ideas and tricks to this problem!

Comment: This is [A004152](http://oeis.org/A004152) in the OEIS.

Comment: @NL628: Typically, people are trying to get the smallest byte count *for a particular language*. So yes, Jelly in this case has very short result; but that hardly makes the results for other languages less fun or interesting for most afficianados of PPCG!

Comment: I'd like this better without the arbitrary restriction of `42<=n<=420`

Comment: Today is Apr 21 for me. Nothing special.

Comment: @JoKing The lower bound doesn't make much sense, but having an explicit upper bound (up to which all submissions must work, regardless of native types) is a good thing.

Comment: Please don't accept an arbitrary answer. [The accepted answer is the answer that wins the challenge.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8712/12012)

Comment: Ah okay, sorry about that

Comment: Alternatively if you don't like it, just don't accept any answer. It's up to you. Anyway... what should be returned if n == -1?

Comment: Ahhh I originally had n >= 42 but ppl told me to delete it. I'll replace it with n = 0

Comment: `0 <= n <= 420` heh

Comment: Why did you accept the Pyt answer when the Neim answer was first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 2 bytes

Explanation: Factorial ; sum .

This outgolfs 3-byte answers as the sum command is able to implicitly convert to a list.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//8PcCZOBeM3//4YGBgA)

Answer (score 5):

## (old problem) [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>99</s> <del>94</del> <s>92</s> <s>88</s> <s>86</s> <s>83</s> <s>80</s> 78 bytes

```javascript
f=(x,t=[...21+Array(999)])=>x?f(s=x-1,t.map(d=>-s+(s+=(t=~~d*x+t/10|0)%10))):s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bchBCsIwEADAu/8Qdk0Tk@ClwlZ8h3gITSNKbUo2SATp16MeBec4N/dw3KfrnOUU/VBrIChNppNSyhpxTMk9oW1bPCN15RCAqUjTZHV3M3jqJAtgQZBpWfymiLw1@qVxbTQi7rn2ceI4DmqMFwhg9KdXv2f/3M5@r74B)

well, first language without large number support

Thank Arnauld for 4 bytes

```javascript
f = (x, t = ['2', '1', ...','.repeat(998)]) => // init x, t=1
  x ?
    f( // recursive x':=x-1, t'=t*x
      s = x-1, // s init to 0 when x==1, in next recursion just return
      t.map (
        b = // init b to NaN
        d =>
          -s + ( //  to return the added value
            s+= ( // -s + (s + k) == k
              b=
                ~~d*x+b/10 | 0
                // ~~d converts ',' to 0
                // b is initally NaN, after first iteration
                // it's zero, then the last digit sum result with carry
            ) % 10
          )
      )
    )
:
  s // the sum from x==1
```

Comment: ps. it doesn't work for 0, but the original question says >=42

Comment: Umm no, it says <= 420  ...

Comment: First version "Given an integer n where 42 <= n <= 420, find the sum of the digits of n!"

Comment: Nice this is what I was looking for...a language that doesn't have the capability of storing massive amounts of digits. Could you explain how it works?

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 24 bytes

```
Total@IntegerDigits[#!]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7PyS/JDHHwTOvJDU9tcglMz2zpDhaWTFW7X@ag@X//7oFRZl5JQA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <strike>42</strike> <strike>40</strike> 38 bytes

```hs
f n=sum[read[d]|d<-show$product[1..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lci9CoAgGEbhvat4h9bEpDGvRBykzyjyDzVauneLaHo4ZzPlsM61tiLIcnqVrSFF@qZ5KFu8@pQjnUtVI2NB6@bNHiBBsQOcrUhvpLyHCob1fQkj55/idxK8PQ)

Thanks to @Laikoni for saving 2 bytes with list comprehension.

Comment: 38 bytes: `f n=sum[read[d]|d<-show$product[1..n]]`.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
!SO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fMdj//38TIwMA)

**Explanation**

```
!     # factorial of input
 S    # split to list of digits
  O   # sum
```

Comment: I really think `O` on a string/non-list should be digit sum. It's come up enough in these non-important challenges.

Answer (score 3):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/attache), 11 bytes

```
Sum@List@`!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fZmX7P7g018Ens7jEIUHxv19qakpxtEpBQXJ6LFdAUWZeSUhqcYlzYnFqcXSajkK0oYGBjoIRiDAxMoiN/Q8A)

`Sum`s the `List` of digits in the factorial (`!`) of the input. Anonymous function.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 16 bytes

```
n->sumdigits(n!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P1664NDclMz2zpFgjT1Hzf2JBQU6lRp6Crp1CQVFmXgmQqQTiKCmkaeRpauooRBsaGOgoGIEIEyODWM3/AA)

Comment: When evaluated on `42000000`, gives `1311426180` (takes under three minutes on my machine). The number has 310,936,107 digits. The average contribution per digit is 4.34, a bit under the "ideal" 4.5, which is likely related to the long string of zero digits in the end.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>13</strike> 11bytes

```
1#.,.&.":@!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8N9QWU9HT01PycpB8b8ml5KegnqarZ66go5CrZVCWjEXV2pyRr5CmoKhgUEFjG2ExDYxArL/AwA)

### Explanation:

`!` calculate the factorial

`@` and

`,.&.":` convert it to a list of digits (convert to string `":`, ravel `,.` and convert each char back to number)

`1#.` find their sum by base-1 conversion

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 21 bytes

```perl6
{[*](2..$_).comb.sum}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1qcqlBmppdszcWVW6mglqZg@786WitWw0hPTyVeUy85PzdJr7g0t/Z/cWKlQpqCoYGBNReEaYRgmhgZWP8HAA)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  [*](       # reduce using &infix:« * »

    2 .. $_  # Range starting at 2 (slight optimization over 1)

  ).comb     # split the result into digits
  .sum       # find the sum of those digits
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + gmp, 66 bytes

```r
sum(strtoi(el(strsplit(paste(gamma(gmp::as.bigz(scan())+1)),""))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcYxDoAgDADAvzi10Rg1TvymKMEmVAitg34e9aarLbGvVG@QYEfeFZteAmrVMkNI/7QkNiikFiCSCEGU4hzp6Dk@oBudgNjPiEPX4aety9Re)

`gmp` is one of the several BigInteger packages available on CRAN.

Comment: `sum(utf8ToInt(as.character(gmp::factorialZ(scan())))-48)` should do the trick as well

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 51 bytes

```python
f=lambda L,p=1:0**L*sum(map(eval,`p`))or f(L-1,p*L)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtLCoAgFAD3neItVV6g0iroBt4ggoySHqQ9@kGnN5vFwCyG32vdk805dJuP0@zBIXem1Uo5dd5RRM9iefyGI49S7gcE4WqDrJzMoSQBJeitRjC6yP5qrB7aCgp8ULqAsFwk8wc)

We'd like to write `` map(int,`p`) ``, but since `repr(p)` might have a trailing `L`, that won't work.

Ordinarily, we'd resort to `map(int,str(p))` and lose three bytes.

Here, can we name our counting-down variable `L`, and write `` map(eval,`p`) ``. Since `L` is 0 when we compute the result, the digit sum is unaffected.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
!DS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/RJfj///8mRgYA)

```
!DS        - main link, taking an integer  e.g. 9
!          - factorial                     -->  362880
 D         - convert to decimal            -->  [3,6,2,8,8,0]
  S        - sum of list                   -->  27
```

Comment: ...you can't be serious...

Comment: DENNIS WHAT DID YOU DO

Comment: @NL628 Python 3 has bigint support, Jelly inherits that.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>52</s> <s>54</s> 52 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,r=1:1/n*sum(map(int,str(r)))or f(n-1,n*r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcsxCsMwDEDROT2FRimoxDaZAjlJ6eASTAW1bBRnyOldD394w693@xYNvaf9F/PniKBsu9/8ovN5ZcyxomjjsxkaERWDhPr0rLNRT4MCovAKjr1zHEZrcO/tMVUbHwgnFOp/)

-2 bytes thx to [Kirill L.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l)

Comment: Could you tell me how to make this challenger harder? I'm kind of struggling right now...

Comment: I believe you need the `f=` as this is a recursive lambda

Comment: @Giuseppe: Quite right! Thx.

Comment: @NL628 don't make the challenge harder after posting it.  That said, if you're looking for some hard challenges for the future, look into mathematical subjects like graph theory, or sets.

Comment: @NL628 Also, you can post it to the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) where it can be refined before posting it to main.

Comment: @ChasBrown, You can get your [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcsxCsMwDEDROT2FRimoxDaZAjlJ6eASTAW1bBRnyOldD394w693@xYNvaf9F/PniKBsu9/8ovN5ZcyxomjjsxkaERWDhPr0rLNRT4MCovAKjr1zHEZrcO/tMVUbHwgnFOp/) back by replacing one of the conditionals with an arithmetical trick.

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash + GNU utilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 36

- 6 bytes saved thanks to @Cowsquack

```bash
seq -s* $1|bc|sed 's/\B\|\\/+&/g'|bc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcqxCoMwFIXh3ac4iK1gCblKt0IHnyOLmmvrklRPxrx76lI6/fDxzxPfZY0HkjItExVbwCDoRc4I7oM84GP1ObaQVtQXwjxRo/n9FTXBmD8U6g7DDk2f5yVTPVpaN7rsnL1d7as9ufgYtHwB)

Comment: Try combining the substitutions into `'s/\B\|\\/+&/g'` https://tio.run/##RcqxCoMwFIXh3ac4iK1gCblKt0IHnyOLmmvrklRPxrx76lI6/fDxzxPfZY0HkjItExVbwCDoRc4I7oM84GP1ObaQVtQXwjxRo/n9FTXBmD8U6g7DDk2f5yVTPVpaN7rsnL1d7as9ufgYtHwB

Comment: @Cowsquack - very good - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
!Ś
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f9f8eis//8NDQwA)

Explanation:

```
      Implicit input
!     Factorial
Ś     Sum of digits
      Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) with Symbolic Package, <s>43</s> 42 bytes

```matlab
@(s)sum(char(sym(['factorial(' s 41]))-48)
```

Anonymous function that takes the input as a string and outputs a nubmer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo1izuDRXIzkjsUijuDJXI1o9LTG5JL8oMzFHQ12hWMHEMFZTU9fEQvN/moa6oYGBuiYXkGEEY5gYARn/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 7 bytes

```
ＩΣΠ…¹⊕Ｎ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI7g0VyOgKD@lNLlEIygxLz1Vw1BHwTMvuSg1NzWvJDVFwzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQxMCrP//NzEy@K9blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
      Ｎ Input as a number
     ⊕  Increment
    ¹   Literal 1
   …    Range
  Π     Product
 Σ      Sum (of digits)
Ｉ       Cast to string
        Implicitly print
```

`InclusiveRange(1, InputNumber())` also works but the explanation is prettier this way.

Answer (score 1):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 54 bytes

```
fn n->Enum.sum Integer.digits Enum.reduce 1..n,&*/2end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcg7CoAwDADQq2SSVjS2HsDNwclDtLEEbJB@wNtH8I2Pbn656HEiS30oNGP0EpB526VnrD3DIY0SFYycuFX4v1DsgcAjyjSMy0oS1aLxzlmrHw)

Ungolfed:

```
def sum_factorial(n) do
  # factorial
  Enum.reduce(1..n, fn(x, acc) -> x * acc end)
  # sum digits
  |> Integer.digits
  |> Enum.sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 107 bytes

```c
f(x){int a[999]={1},i,c;
for(;x;--x)for(c=i=0;i<999;)c=(a[i]=a[i]*x+c)/10,a[i++]%=10;
for(;i--;)x+=a[i];
i=x;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5BjsIwDEX3OUXEqFI8TcBFbCqTXqR0UaUELEE6AkaKqHr2kgAb@3/528/OnJxbFq8iTBwesm/ruu7sVM2atSM/3hRFMiZCls6yReJ9yhA4q/qWO5vLbywdbCrUyZRlV9gKP7tsDEEs3yFiG2lefji4y/9w3N8fA4/rcyMy@NpzUDAJmU1o0wu7Leotoq4QZxIyn8sztnd@Hkcvw@YrsA1dBjVIIKT8u6WYV6tikKaRxXAIKx0SXnuVGwCJeXkB)

Comment: `a[i++]%=10` into the `for`

Comment: `c;f(x){int a[999]={1},i;for(;x;--x)for(i=0;i<999;a[i++]%=10)c=(a[i]=a[i]*x+c)/10;for(;i--;)x+=a[i];i=x;}`

Comment: `c;i;f(x){int a[999]={x},n;for(;--x;)for(i=n=0;i<999;n+=a[i++]%=10)c=(a[i]=a[i]*x+c)/10;i=n;}`

Comment: [104 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY3BCsIwEETv@YqgFBKb6Fa8lDX9kdpDSY0uaCq2QrD022uiXnZnmNl9Vl@sXRYngpzIj7yty7JszFTMipRF1z8FBtQ6yCStIQNIx9jBtqY8bzJTgLQmmuY7NiG3uwJ@h6Q1ypB/AyQTcF7W5O3t1Z2Pw9hRv71WLFHvLXkhJ8aT8XXkH/ag9gCqAJiR8fQuZWQGep97x/3uL6D2TQJVgJJx/njGmhOrrOO64ll38ivlI145kZaUyOblAw)

Comment: @l4m2 why the i=n part then? `c;n;f(x){int a[999]={x},i;for(;--x;)for(i=n=0;i<999;n+=a[i++]%=10)c=(a[i]=a[i]*x+c)/10;}` Though fails for x=0 now that the lower bound has been edited out of the challenge.

Comment: @l4m2 and one less: `c;n;f(x){for(int a[999]={x},i;--x;)for(i=n=0;i<999;n+=a[i++]%=10)c=(a[i]=a[i]*x+c)/10;}` (87)

Comment: @RomanOdaisky `i=n` because i didn't know if the ret value is correct without it. with gastropner's it's `c;n;f(x){for(int a[999]={x},i;--x;)for(i=n=0;i<999;n+=a[i++]%=10)c=a[i]=a[i]*x+c/10;}` (85)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

```
ΣdΠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fG3xoSWrxo6bG/@cWp5xb8P///2hDAwMdIyA2MTKIBQA)

#### Explanation

```
ΣdΠ  Implicit input
  Π  Factorial
 d   Convert to list of digits
Σ    Sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 33 bytes

```ruby
->n{(2..n).inject(:*).digits.sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWsNITy9PUy8zLys1uUTDSktTLyUzPbOkWK@4NLf2f4FCWrSJkUHsfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 78 bytes

```
proc S n {proc F n {expr $n?($n)*\[F $n-1]:1}
expr [join [split [F $n] ""] +]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WSFYIU@hGsxyA7FSKwqKFFTy7DVU8jS1YqLdgGxdw1grw1ousEx0Vn5mnkJ0cUFOZokCWDZWQUkpVkE7tvZ/Tm5iAcgILkMDAy4jIDYxMuCqBRpeWlIMVGgVoxAdDNJQ@x8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
║▼⌡è
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=ba1ff58a&i=100%0A%0A200%0A%0A420&m=1)

#### Unpacked (5 bytes) and explanation

```
|FE|+
|F       Implicit input. Factorial.
  E      Array of decimal digits.
   |+    Sum of list. Implicit print.
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Python**](https://www.python.org/), 75 bytes

```
import math
print(sum(map(int,list(str(math.factorial(int(input())))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 10, 135 bytes

```java
n->{var r=java.math.BigInteger.ONE;for(;!n.equals(r.ZERO);n=n.subtract(r.ONE))r=r.multiply(n);return(r+"").chars().map(c->c-48).sum();}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##pVCxTsMwEN37FUcnWyhWqTogWemA1IGBRKIbiOHqOqmD44SzHamq8u3BBNg6gXQ33N17d@9dgwNmzfF9Uha9hyc07rIAMC5oqlBpKL7KuQGKNQktWgwn8WDqx4SpNYHjMkHGlCl8wGAUFOAgh8ll28uABJRfY4qy2MmqIyZvnNAfEa1nJF52zyWXLnfCx0MgVIHNSM4pJ9FGG0xvzyxdJR0iOUa3yyUX6oTkGU83eqayrco29zxtaBmX4yQXSVofDzZJ@1E4dOYIbbLL9oGMq1/fAPm31/3ZB92KLgbRp1Gwjjlx3bwY0EZdVuxuteJ8fsTf@Ot/8jfrX/64GKdP)

```java
n->{                         // Method with BigInteger parameter and integer return-type
  var r=java.math.BigInteger.ONE;
                             //  BigInteger, starting at 1
  for(;!n.equals(r.ZERO);    //  Loop as long as `n` is not 0 yet
      n=n.subtract(r.ONE))   //    After every iteration: subtract 1 from `n`
    r=r.multiply(n);         //   Multiply `r` by `n`
  return(r+"").chars()       //  Loop over the characters of `r`
              .map(c->c-48)  //   Convert them to digits
              .sum();}       //   And return the sum of those digits
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ceylon, 98 bytes

```ceylon
import ceylon.whole{l=one}Integer q(Integer n)=>sum({0,*product({l,*(l:n)}).string*.offset('0')});
```

[Try it online](https://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=5c2e0772578a68dab9f3d51c3d9a9ac7)

### Explanation:

This is quite long, because we need to convince the compiler that we are not doing bogus stuff.

```ceylon
import ceylon.whole { l = one } // 1

Integer q(Integer n) => // 2
    sum({0,*product({l,*(l:n)}).string *.offset('0')});
//  |   |   |       |    '3' || |    | | |         |||
//  |   |   |       '--4-----'| |    | 7 |         ||| 
//  |   |   '----5------------' '-6--'   '--8------'||
//  |   |   '----------------9---------------------'||
//  |   '----------------10-------------------------'|
//  '------------------------11----------------------'
```

1. Import the value [`one`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/whole/1.3.3/module-doc/api/index.html#one) from the package `ceylon.whole`,
   and give it locally the name `l` (small L, not the digit `1` – though I choose this alias for its similarity to 1). (This alias import costs two bytes here, but saves two bytes for each of the two usages).
2. Define a function `q` from `Integer` to `Integer`, which maps
   each parameter `n` to the result of the following expression (calculated in steps 3 to 11). Top-level functions always need a type declaration. For local ones we could replace the return type by `function`, which wouldn't have saved anything here. (For inline functions, we sometimes can omit both types and the keyword, if they can be inferred from context.)
3. This is a short syntax for [`measure(one, n)`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.3.3/module-doc/api/index.html#measure), which returns either the empty sequence `[]` if `n` is non-positive, or a `Range<Whole>` starting from `one` and having size `n` (i.e. all numbers from 1 to n, assuming n is a positive integer).  Type: `[]|Range<Whole>`, which is a subtype of `{Whole*}` (possibly empty iterable of Whole).
4. This is an [iterable enumeration](https://www.ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.3/reference/expression/iterable/), with `one` as the first element and then all the elements of `one:n` (the `*` here expands the iterable). This has type `{Whole+}`, and has the only purpose to make sure the compiler knows it is non-empty. We could have used `[...]` instead of `{...}` for a [tuple enumeration](https://www.ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.3/reference/expression/tuple/) (which is non-lazy). No difference here apart from performance. We could have written this [`(l:n).follow(l)`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.3.3/module-doc/api/Iterable.type.html#follow), but that is longer.
5. Calculate the product of all those numbers, type `Whole`. [`product`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.3.3/module-doc/api/index.html#product) needs a non-empty iterable as a parameter to work (as the product of nothing is not defineable in a type-independent way).
6. Get the string representation of the result of step 5. (The `.string` attribute exists for all classes, and `Whole` implements it in the expected way, using decimal digits.) – type `String`, which is also a `{Character*}` (possibly empty iterable of characters).
7. The [`*.` operator](https://www.ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.3/reference/operator/spread-invoke/) for iterables applies the the following attribute or method call to each element of the iterable and collects the result in a sequence. It can be seen as syntactic sugar for `.collect(c => c.offset('0'))`. This is non-lazily evaluated, there is also `.map(...)` which is lazy.
8. The [`offset`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.3.3/module-doc/api/Character.type.html#offset) method of `Character` just calculates the difference between the unicode code points, returning an `Integer`.
   This takes advantage of the fact that the ten decimal digits are sequential starting with `0` in ASCII (and thus unicode).
9. This whole thing has now type `[Integer*]` (possibly empty sequence of integers – because the string is possibly empty for the compiler).
10. Same trick again as step 4, we make it an `{Integer+}` (nonempty iterable) by prepending a `0` (which has no effect on the following sum).
11. [Sum](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.3.3/module-doc/api/index.html#sum) it all up.

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <strike>11</strike> 8 bytes

there is in fact a better way to get a list of digits

```
lim!Ab:+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/PyczV9ExyUr7/38TIwMA)

Explanation:

```
li          input, convert to integer
  m!        factorial
    Ab      convert to array of digits in base 10
      :+    sum
```

---

Original solution:

```
lim!`1/:i:+
```

Explanation:

```
li              input converted to integer
  m!            factorial
    `           convert to string
     1/         split into pieces of length 1
       :i       convert back to integer
         :+     sum
```